# What is the recommended way to load an external configuration file in Wildfly (Swarm)?

Tags: configuration, yaml, wildfly, external, wildfly-swarm

I want to be able to specify an external configuration file when starting upp my Wildfly Swarm application. What is the recommended way to do it?

I have seen annotations like *@ConfigValue* and *@Configured* being mentioned, but I haven't gotten them to work and most places mentioning them are documents about developing fractions. Can I still use them? Seems to be hard to find any documentation about them.

Can I maybe get access to the arguments given to the Wildfly Swarm application when it was started? In that case I could specify the path to the configuration file as an argument and then parse the file myself.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2018.1.0-SNAPSHOT/#configuring-an-application-using-yaml

It explains how to configure a project-defaults.yml, and then you can @Inject the value with @ConfigurationValue("some.key")

Answer (score 0):

I have now found an answer to my question thanks to that **Ken** verified that using *@ConfigurationValue* is a feasible solution.

At the beginning I tried to use this annotation but it didn't work. I realised that I was using **CDI** wrongly rather than **Wildfly Swarm**. My previous code looked like following:

```
@Default
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationHandlerImpl implements ConfigurationHandler {

    @Inject @ConfigurationValue("wishlist.test")
    private String test;

    @Inject
    public ConfigurationHandlerImpl(Logger logger) { ... }
}
```

The problem was that while the variable *logger* got a value the *test* variable stayed *null*. Seems I can't have two *@Inject* like this. The solution was to add the *test* variable to the constructor. Then both *logger* and *test* were assigned a value correctly, as seen below.

```
@Default
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationHandlerImpl implements ConfigurationHandler {

    @Inject
    public ConfigurationHandlerImpl(Logger logger, @ConfigurationValue("test.test") String test) { ... }

}
```